# Useful security key/crypto testing software

Tags: encryption, software-testing, unit-tests, cryptography

<sub>Would prefer open source. Open to commercial recommendations if you can explain why there is no other good option.</sub>

Looking for software that can more or less *black box test* for **strength** and **vulnerabilities** of diffie-helman exchanges and Elliptical Curve Crypto signed keys. Working on a embedded product with hardware-enabled AES crypto along with 3rd-party libraries to help manage security key&cert creation and exchanges.

I know there's a lot of material out there for creating these sorts of things (keys&certs to be used with either scheme), but I'm specifically looking for something for **testing** them. As a minimal example, would want to verify our implementation does not effectively generate "snake oil" certs/keys.

> **Related links**
>
> [security.SE: Logjam attack vulnerability](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/how-to-check-if-a-server-is-not-vulnerable-to-logjam)
>
> [crypto.SE: check if an ECC is secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15507/is-there-an-algorithm-to-check-if-an-elliptic-curve-is-secure)

Any modern OS would be acceptable provided it's not too obtuse, although a good answer could specify the required OS and comment on it as an advantage/disadvantage. It's a commercial project, so price should be reasonable but not a limiting factor. That's part of why I prefaced my post with *Would prefer open source. Open to commercial recommendations if you can explain why there is no other good option.* As far as I'm concerned, Kali linux would not be obtuse, if it had the best option(s). If Windows, there may be higher buy-in to adopt the tool(s).

Comment: I don't think you can get away with one tool. Maybe one testing environment if you're lucky. Randomness tests, logical tests, timing attacks, IO validation etc. etc. etc.